# Validate if a keyed table have unique keys

Tags: kdb, k

How to check if a table have unique keys?
For one key-column it works:

```
t:([k1:1 2 3]d:10 20 30);
@[{update `u#k1 from t};`;{"Err: ",x}]
```

But how to do the same for multiple key columns?

```
t:([k1:1 2 2; k2:`a`b`b]d:10 20 30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This following should work, assuming you are looking for unique key value as vectors, the following will give a boolean yes or no

```
t:([k1:1 2 2; k2:`a`b`b]d:10 20 30)
{count[x]~count distinct x}  flip value flip key t
```

If you are asking if each key column is unique then you can do the following

```
t:([k1:1 2 2; k2:`a`b`b]d:10 20 30)
@[`u#;flip value flip key t;'"not unique"]
```

Comment: you probably meant ```@[`u#;flip value flip key t;{'"not unique"}]```?

Comment: Good catch haha